# Add a key object to metadata - Couchbase

Tags: metadata, couchbase, sql++

Is there a way I can add a **custom key-value pair** to this metadata object in **couchbase**?

Thanks.[Below image is a screenshot of meta data of one document added in couchbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO1vg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta listed are specific to Couchbase. You can explore extended attributes (xattr):

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/developer-guide/extended-attributes-fundamentals.html

> The Couchbase SDK supports the creation and modification of extended
> attributes by applications written in Node.js, Java, .NET, PHP,
> Python, Go, and C. This is achieved by extensions to the Subdocument
> API.

So, yes, you can read/write to the `xattrs` if you want to. But:

> Couchbase Server provides no facility for enumerating or sharing
> knowledge of extended attributes: therefore, no application has
> knowledge of the extended attributes within a document other than
> their creator; unless such knowledge is shared explicitly between
> applications by some mechanism external to Couchbase Server

Any data you store in xattr counts against the total size limit of the document. xattr values should really only be used at a lower framework level, and not for any sort of business logic or data. So, make sure you have a really good reason to be reading/writing xattr. (Some examples of how Couchbase uses it are for ACID transactions and mobile sync).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, our use case is, when a document gets deleted we have written a eventing on delete and want to make a api call. But I need to pass a value which is inside the document to that rest call. Now in on delete function of eventing, we have only access to meta object. So that's the reason I am planning to save that custom value in meta and read it in on delete function. Is there any other way to implement this functionality.

Comment: See forum for further discussion: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/add-a-key-object-to-metadata/28813